# error when initializing variable

Tags: c++

I am fairly new to `C++`.
and i'm making a `tic tac toe` game, where i need a random generator to decide which player goes first.
but i got some error when initializing the variable.

Here is the code

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
#include "Board.h"
#include "Player.h"

class manager
{
public:
    manager();
    void gameEntrance();
    void playGame();
    void askMove();
    void diceRoll();
    void winChekcer();
    void endGameChecker();

private:
    default_random_engine _randomGenerator(time(0)); //here i got "Error: functio "time" is not a type name
    uniform_real_distribution<float> _diceRoll(0.0f, 1.0f); //here i got "Error: expected a type specifier
    bool _endGame = false;
    string _turn;
    Board _board;
    Player _player1;
    Player _player2;
};
```

so what did i do wrong. Please enlighten me. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instance member fields should be initialized in constructors at the definition of that constructor

```
manager::manager() 
  : _randomGenerator(time(0)), _diceRoll(0.0f, 1.0f), endGame(false) 
  {}
```

this would go in your `manager.cc` implementation file, not in your `manager.h` header file.

Comment: And put them in order of the declaration

Comment: thank you so much. it helps me.
ok time to go to the next error.

Answer (score 1):

either use constructor to initialize variables:

```
manager::manager() 
: _randomGenerator(time(0)), _diceRoll(0.0f, 1.0f) 
{}
```

or `=` with full construction

```
default_random_engine _randomGenerator = default_random_engine(time(0));
uniform_real_distribution<float> _diceRoll = uniform_real_distribution<float>(0.0f, 1.0f);
```

or `=` with initializer list:

```
default_random_engine _randomGenerator = { time(0) };
uniform_real_distribution<float> _diceRoll = { 0.0f, 1.0f };
```

*the last one is untested, `= time(0)` may work as well, may depend on possible conversion operators*

your direct constructor calls `default_random_engine _randomGenerator(time(0));` can only be used for static/const variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in C++11, do

`uniform_real_distribution<float> _diceRoll{0.0f, 1.0f};`

And when you write `default_random_engine _randomGenerator(***);` the compiler is considering you are define a function whose name is `randomGenerator` which returns  `default_random_engine`, and waiting for type at the place of `time(0)`